# What does the Source Control exclamation mark means in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control

[image: Source Control icons in VS 2013]

Can anyone tell me please what does mean that red exclamation mark in Source Control ?

Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd recommend you to reconsider usage of using statement. If to speak particularly about db connections, and your code, then you first should close connection, and then dispose it. But using statement will close and dispose connection automatically ( during compile time it will be expanded with usage of appropriate IDisposable interface ). 
Second as already mentioned, before disposing connection, you should close it.

And about your questions. 
Q1. As usually connection string value is located in .config file ( app.config of web.config ), and read directly from section connection string, in order not to confuse other developers which will co-work with you or continue support of your project. 
Q2.Exception type will catch all possible cases of exceptions. That is relatively fine, but if you want to be more accurate, you can apply other exceptions before Exception. For example you can also add OleDbException. 
Q3. I recommend you to reconsider your decision WRT using statement, because .Net compiler knows when to call close method, and then dispose, and when to call just close method better ( except WCF services). So if you don't work with WCF I recommend you to use using statement.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question